# CKContainer fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler returns nil CKRecordID when iCloud Drive is disabled

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Whenever I try to call `CKContainer`'s `fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler` function I am unable to get a `CKRecordID` when iCloud Drive is disabled on the device's iCloud settings. The error returned is same one I would get as if the device had no linked iCloud account.

I am calling:

```
CKContainer.defaultContainer().fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler { (recordId, error) {
   //recordId is nil iff iCloud Drive is off
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
<CKError 0x125647120: "Not Authenticated" (9/1002); "CloudKit access was denied by user settings"; Retry after 3.0 seconds>
```

If I switch iCloud Drive on everything works as normal. Is this behaviour per design or did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's working as designed. iCloud Drive is a requirement to use CloudKit. This is documented in the [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987).

Look under the [Enter iCloud Credentials Before Running Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH3-SW12) section.

Comment: That settles this. Thanks @rmaddy.